# Trying to center page in every type of browser --- works in most, not in others

Tags: html, css

I've done a very simple html set of pages for this site:
http://www.soilexpress.com/environmental.php

on most devices, it centers correctly within the size of the browser window, with equal margins on either side.

I've had some reports of specific problem machines though:

On ie10 (large screen laptop) it looked off-center to the right.

On iphone 4G (portrait or landscape) the page was off-center to the right.

I'm wondering if someone can tell me the device/browser specific lines to put at the top so it will always be centered.

I believe the problem comes from my identification (or lack) of the type of document at the top of the page and thinking maybe I should add some If statement at the top to allow for a more strict document type for certain browsers????

As it is now, it is merely identified as `html`.  If I change the description to a more detailed type, it changes the centering.

I appreciate the help.  thanks.

---

### Here is the text from the example above -- environmental.php

```
<html>
<head><title>Environmental - SoilExpress</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
img { border-style: none;}
td {color:#ffffff; font-size:15px; font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; font-weight: 300; }
.footer {color:#999999; font-size:12px; font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; font-weight: 300; }
.whiteheader {color:#ffffff; font-size:20px; font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; font-weight: 300; }
.redheaderblower {color:#cc0000; font-size:30px; font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; float: right; font-weight: 900; }
.redheadereow {color:#ff0000; font-size:30px; font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; float: left; font-weight: 900; }
-->
</style>
</head>
<body background='/web_images/level3-background.png' marginheight="0" topmargin="0">
<!-- master table -->
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr><td width='50%'><img src='/web_images/trs.gif' height='1' width='1'></td>
<td valign="top" width="1200">
<!-- content table -->
<table width="1200" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="1200" colspan='6'>
<a href='/'>
<img src='/web_images/row-header.png' width='1200' height='120' style='vertical-align: top;'>
</a>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- ROW navigation -->
<tr>
<td>
<img src='/web_images/row-nav1.png' width='207' height='136' style='vertical-align: top;'>
</td>

<td>
<a href='/safety.php'>
<img src='/web_images/row-nav-safety.png' width='185' height='136' style='vertical-align: top;'>
</a>
</td>

<td>
<a href='/equipment.php'>
<img src='/web_images/row-nav-equipment.png' width='220' height='136' style='vertical-align: top;'>
</a>
</td>

<td>
<a href='/capable.php'>
<img src='/web_images/row-nav-capable.png' width='165' height='136' style='vertical-align: top;'>
</a>
</td>

<td>
<a href='/environmental.php'>
<img src='/web_images/row-nav-environmental.png' width='218' height='136' style='vertical-align: top;'>
</a>
</td>

<td>
<img src='/web_images/row-nav1.png' width='205' height='136' style='vertical-align: top;'>
</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="1200" colspan='6'>
<img src='/web_images/environmental.png' width='1200' height='750'>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="1200" colspan='6'>
<table width='1200' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0'>
<tr><td bgcolor='black'>
<img src='/web_images/trs.gif' width='381' height='1'>
</td>
<td bgcolor='black'>
<a href='/contact.php'>
<img src='/web_images/footer-contact-link.png' width='123' height='92' style='vertical-align: top;'>
</a>
</td>
<td bgcolor='black'>
<a href='/'>
<img src='/web_images/footer-home-link.png' width='196' height='92' style='vertical-align: top;'>
</a>
</td>
<td bgcolor='black'>
<img src='/web_images/footer-copyright.png' width='500' height='92' style='vertical-align: top;'>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</td><td width='50%'><img src='/web_images/trs.gif' height='1' width='1'></td>
</tr></table>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Don't uuse `table` for layout purposes

Comment: You're using some very archaic HTML. Use CSS for styling, not attributes like `width`, `background`, etc

Comment: Use CSS Resets they always help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;background-color:white;width:100%;font-family:Trebuchet MS,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;font-size:20px;">
     <div align="center">
          <div style="width:980px;text-align:left;">
          /*Write within this and it will be centered*/
          </div>
     </div>
</span>
```

I just used the inline CSS for the divs for little line of code.

Hope this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out for the ie10 notebooks ... their screen width is less than the 1200 pixel width of the main image ... therefore it shows on the left side like normal and bleeds off on the right, making it look off-center.

Made the center image 900 px wide and now it works perfect.

Not sure about the iphone5 yet, but hoping that will work the same.

The reason I chose to do straight old-fashioned html vs. css is because the whole page is just two images. One header with a link and one body image. This means it can look identical on every browser once I get the centering right. If I try to center using CSS, I run into version issues. Since I don't have true text anyway, it seems like a waste of time without consistent results.

I appreciate your reply!  will use it on another :)